# Installing dotnet new template not working from NuGet Feed, works locally

Tags: .net, nuget

Looking for some guidance on fault finding an install from `dotnet new -i <NUGET_PACKAGE_ID>`

I have a template which is packaged and deployed to an Azure Devops NuGet Feed. I can't install this template when I use the `dotnet new -i <NUGET_PACKAGE_ID>`  However I'm able to install it if I download `.nupkg` file from nuget server and install it from the file system.

I get no diagnostics messages from the install process. Is there a way of seeing detailed messaging on what is wrong with this template. I'm suspecting it's an auth problem or similar.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I've hit the same issue

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of seeing detailed messaging on what is wrong with this template.

You can add add the `DOTNET_CLI_CONTEXT_VERBOSE` environment variable with value `true` to get more verbose logging.

Then you will get the actual error, which is most likely an authorization issue:

> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

In that case you need to install the [Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) and run the install command interactively once again:

> dotnet new -i <NUGET_PACKAGE_ID> --interactive

Then you will get instructions on how to authenticate with the Azure Devops NuGet feed.
See [Unable to install template from Azure DevOps Nuget Feed issue](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/4162#issuecomment-985523894) for more details.